# How to prove that $\Bbb{P}(X_{4l} = 0) \leq c_l (2d)^{-2l}$ for some constant $c_l$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Let $(X_n)$ be a simple random walk on $\Bbb{Z}^d$ starting at $0$. (The dimension $d$ will vary, but I will suppress the dependence on $d$ for brevity.) I encountered a statement which claims that

> For any $l = 1, 2, \cdots$, there exists a constant $c_l > 0$ (depending only on $l$) such that
>   $$\Bbb{P}(X_{4l} = 0) \leq c_l (2d)^{-2l}.$$

It was given without any explanation, so I tried to prove it by myself and was able to check this with some dirty calculation using complex analysis(!).

But I would like to know how to prove this using probability theory or any intuition on why this should be true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the claim trivial? We can simply choose $c_l := (2d)^{2l}$ and then the inequality is (trivally) satisfied. Do you want to show that $c_l$ can be chosen independent from $d$ or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @saz, Yes, I want that $c_l$ depends only on $l$. I thought the notation is self-explanatory, though it seems not. I will explicitly mention it.

Comment: I see; thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n_i,n_{-i},i=1,\dots,d$ denote a move of a (simple symmetric) RW in $i$-th  and the opposite direction, respectively. Then

$$P\{X_{2n}=0\}=P\{n_1=n_{-1},\dots,n_d=n_{-d}\}$$
$$=\sum_{n_1+n_{-1}\cdots+n_d+n_{-d}=2n}1\{n_1=n_{-1},\dots,n_d=n_{-d}\}\binom{2n}{n_1,n_{-1}\dots,n_d,n_{-d}}\left(\frac{1}{d}\right)^{2n}$$

$$=(2d)^{-2n} \binom{2n}{n} \sum_{n_1+\dots+n_d=n}\binom{n}{n_1,\dots,n_d}^2$$
$$\le (2d)^{-n}2^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}\sum_{n_1+\dots+n_d=n}M_{n,d}\binom{n}{n_1,\dots,n_d} \left(\frac{1}{d}\right)^n=(2d)^{-n}2^{-n}M_{n,d}\binom{2n}{n}$$

where $M_{n,d}$ is the maximum of $\binom{n}{n_1,\dots,n_d}$ over all $n_1\dots,n_d$ s.t. $n_1+\cdots +n_d=n$ which is attained at $n_1=n_2=\cdots=n_d=n/d$.

Comment: And of course $M_{n,d} \leq n!$, which removes the dependence on $d$. Thank you! I derived the same combinatoric expression but had no idea to control factorial squares directly. I am happy to see that this simple bound does the job. I first tried to estimate the size of $M_{n,d}$ using Stirling approximation, but this did not work because for large $d$, most of $n_1, \cdots, n_d$ are just 0.